# Run a function for each element in two lists in Pandas Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas

**df**:

```
col1
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', '2']
['this', 'list', '3']

col2
[['ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'], ['qq', 'ww', 'ee', 'rr']]
[['list', 'a', 'not', '1'], ['not', 'is', 'this', '2']]
[['this', 'is', 'list', 'not'], ['a', 'not', 'list', '2']]
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

I am trying to run the code below on each element (word) in df `col1` on each corresponding element in each of the sublists in `col2`, and put the scores in a new column.

So for the first row in `col1`, run the `get_top_matches` function on this:

```
`col1` "aa" and `col2` "ee" and "qq"
`col1` "bb" and `col2` "ff" and "ww"
`col1` "cc" and `col2` "gg" and "ee"
`col1` "dd" and `col2` "hh" and "rr"
```

**What the new column should look like:**

*I don't know for sure what row 2 and 3 scores should be*

```
score_col
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[.34, .33, .27, .24, .23] #not sure
[.23, .13, .26] #not sure
```

**What I've tried before:**

I've done when `col1` was just a string against each list element in `col2`, like this, but i don't have the slightest idea how to run it against list elements to corresponding sublist elements:

```
df.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(*x), axis=1)
```

.
.
.
.

**The Function Code**

Here's the `get_top_matches` function - just run this whole thing; i'm only calling the last function for this question:

```
#jaro version
def sort_token_alphabetically(word):
    token = re.split('[,. ]', word)
    sorted_token = sorted(token)
    return ' '.join(sorted_token)

def get_jaro_distance(first, second, winkler=True, winkler_ajustment=True,
                      scaling=0.1, sort_tokens=True):
    """
    :param first: word to calculate distance for
    :param second: word to calculate distance with
    :param winkler: same as winkler_ajustment
    :param winkler_ajustment: add an adjustment factor to the Jaro of the distance
    :param scaling: scaling factor for the Winkler adjustment
    :return: Jaro distance adjusted (or not)
    """
    if sort_tokens:
        first = sort_token_alphabetically(first)
        second = sort_token_alphabetically(second)

    if not first or not second:
        raise JaroDistanceException(
            "Cannot calculate distance from NoneType ({0}, {1})".format(
                first.__class__.__name__,
                second.__class__.__name__))

    jaro = _score(first, second)
    cl = min(len(_get_prefix(first, second)), 4)

    if all([winkler, winkler_ajustment]):  # 0.1 as scaling factor
        return round((jaro + (scaling * cl * (1.0 - jaro))) * 100.0) / 100.0

    return jaro

def _score(first, second):
    shorter, longer = first.lower(), second.lower()

    if len(first) > len(second):
        longer, shorter = shorter, longer

    m1 = _get_matching_characters(shorter, longer)
    m2 = _get_matching_characters(longer, shorter)

    if len(m1) == 0 or len(m2) == 0:
        return 0.0

    return (float(len(m1)) / len(shorter) +
            float(len(m2)) / len(longer) +
            float(len(m1) - _transpositions(m1, m2)) / len(m1)) / 3.0

def _get_diff_index(first, second):
    if first == second:
        pass

    if not first or not second:
        return 0

    max_len = min(len(first), len(second))
    for i in range(0, max_len):
        if not first[i] == second[i]:
            return i

    return max_len

def _get_prefix(first, second):
    if not first or not second:
        return ""

    index = _get_diff_index(first, second)
    if index == -1:
        return first

    elif index == 0:
        return ""

    else:
        return first[0:index]

def _get_matching_characters(first, second):
    common = []
    limit = math.floor(min(len(first), len(second)) / 2)

    for i, l in enumerate(first):
        left, right = int(max(0, i - limit)), int(
            min(i + limit + 1, len(second)))
        if l in second[left:right]:
            common.append(l)
            second = second[0:second.index(l)] + '*' + second[
                                                       second.index(l) + 1:]

    return ''.join(common)

def _transpositions(first, second):
    return math.floor(
        len([(f, s) for f, s in zip(first, second) if not f == s]) / 2.0)

def get_top_matches(reference, value_list, max_results=None):
    scores = []
    if not max_results:
        max_results = len(value_list)
    for val in value_list:
        score_sorted = get_jaro_distance(reference, val)
        score_unsorted = get_jaro_distance(reference, val, sort_tokens=False)
        scores.append((val, max(score_sorted, score_unsorted)))
    scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return scores[:max_results]

class JaroDistanceException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(Exception, self).__init__(message)
```

.
.
.

---

**Attempt 1**
Just trying to get this to compare to each word in the lists rather than each letter:

```
[[[df1.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,w), axis=1) for u,w in zip(x,v)]\ for v in y] for x,y in zip(df1['parent_org_name_list'], df1['children_org_name_sublists'])]
```

[image: Results]

**Attempt 2**
Changing the `get_top_matches` function to say `for val in value_list.split():` resulted in this below - which grabs the first word and compares it to the first word in each sublist in `col2` 5 times (not sure why 5 times):

```
[
  [0    [(myalyk, 0.73)]1    [(myalyk, 0.73)]2    [(myalyk, 0.73)]3    [(myalyk, 0.73)]4    [(myalyk, 0.73)]dtype: object]
, [0    [(myliu, 0.79)]1    [(myliu, 0.79)]2    [(myliu, 0.79)]3    [(myliu, 0.79)]4    [(myliu, 0.79)]dtype: object]
, [0    [(myllc, 0.97)]1    [(myllc, 0.97)]2    [(myllc, 0.97)]3    [(myllc, 0.97)]4    [(myllc, 0.97)]dtype: object]
, [0    [(myloc, 0.88)]1    [(myloc, 0.88)]2    [(myloc, 0.88)]3    [(myloc, 0.88)]4    [(myloc, 0.88)]dtype: object]
]
```

Just need the function to run on each word in the sublists.

**Attempt 3**
Removing the second attempt code from the `get_top_matches` function and modifying the attempt one list comprehension code to below, grabbed the first word in the first 3 sublists in `col2`; need to compare against the `col1` list to each word in the `col2` sublists:

```
[[df.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,v), axis=1) for u in x ]
    for v in zip(*y)]
        for x,y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])
]
```

**results to attempt 3**

```
[[0    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...1    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...2    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...3    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...4    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...dtype: object]]
```

**Expectation**
(this example: row 1 has 4 sublists, row 2 has 2 sublists. the function runs on each word in each column 1 for each word in each sublist in column 2 and puts the results in a sublist in a new column.)

```
[[['myalyk',.97], ['oleksandr',.54], ['nychyporovych',.3], ['pp',0]], [['myliu',.88], ['srl',.43]], [['myllc',1.0]], [['myloc',1.0], ['manag',.45], ['IT',.1], ['ag',0]]], 
[[['ltd',.34], ['yuriapharm',.76]], [['yuriypra',.65], ['law',.54], ['offic',.45], ['pc',.34]]],
...
```

Comment: TLDR: what is your question?

Comment: @deadshot don't worry about the functions at the bottom. you just run that and it generates a score when comparing two strings.

Comment: then remove the code that is not needed

Comment: @deadshot trying to run the last function at the bottom (which uses all of the other functions in that code) on elements in two lists - and the second list has sublists.

Comment: @deadshot it's all needed in order to reproduce the results

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: @deadshot it's there - under the `what the new column should look like`

Comment: Can you show clearly how your DF is set up?

Comment: @ifly6 Just Added a picture at the bottom of the post

Comment: @ifly6 or @deadshot Hey guys - I've made a little bit of progress on this, wondering if y'all are interested in helping me figure it out. Here's the code i've come up with so far - but this compares the letters in each list/sublist, rather than the word `[[[df1.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,w), axis=1) for u,w in zip(x,v)]\
for v in y] for x,y in zip(df1['parent_org_name_list'], df1['children_org_name_sublists'])]` I added a screenshot of what this produces in the post

Comment: Try to substitute `for val in value_list:` with `for val in value_list.split():` in your `get_top_matches` function. And than use list comprehension you written.

Comment: @StasBuzuluk This is kind of close. It applies the function per word, but the same word in col1: `[[0    [(myllc,, 0.73)]1    [(myllc,, 0.73)]2    [(myllc,, 0.73)]3    [(myllc,, 0.73)]4    [(myllc,, 0.73)]dtype: object], [0    [(myllc,, 0.79)]1    [(myllc,, 0.79)]2    [(myllc,, 0.79)]3    [(myllc,, 0.79)]4    [(myllc,, 0.79)]dtype: object], [0    [(myllc,, 0.97)]1    [(myllc,, 0.97)]2    [(myllc,, 0.97)]3    [(myllc,, 0.97)]4    [(myllc,, 0.97)]dtype: object], [0    [(myllc,, 0.88)]1    [(myllc,, 0.88)]2    [(myllc,, 0.88)]3    [(myllc,, 0.88)]4    [(myllc,, 0.88)]dtype: object]]`

Comment: @StasBuzuluk any other ideas? I feel like the code `[[[df1.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,w), axis=1) for u,w in zip(x,v)]\ for v in y] for x,y in zip(df1['parent_org_name_list'], df1['children_org_name_sublists'])]` can be changed slightly - maybe one of the for loops can be modified slightly and it will do the right operation. I just don't know these for loops/list comprehension code that well.

Comment: To be honest - your question is a little bit unclear for me :(
Try to remove my previous try and substitute your list comprehensions with:
`[[[df.agg(lambda x: get_top_matches(u,v), axis=1) for u in x ] for v in zip(*y)] for x,y in zip(df['col_1'], df['col_2'])]`

Comment: @StasBuzuluk I know it's a very very tricky piece of code to write. This is what your last suggestion did (with removing the first one): ```[[0    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...1    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...2    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...3    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...4    [(myllc, 0.97), (myloc, 0.88), (myliu, 0.79), 
...dtype: object]]``` - this is close - it's grabbing the first word in the first three sublists in col2. Need to compare to each word in each sublist in col2

Comment: I added a better view of the results to `Attempt 3` in the bottom of the post.

Comment: what do you want to happen if the list in one row of col1 has fewer elements than one sublist of the col2? Please give us an example.

Comment: @BillyBonaros hey I just added an expectations example at the bottom of the post. let me know what you think

Comment: @max, this post is too long. Can you change the way you ask. I would like to see what's the source df, whats the expected df, whats the logic to get from source to expected. That will help. All other info is noise.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I made a new post trying to simplify the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911177/list-comprehension-with-nested-for-loops-on-sublists-within-pandas-df-columns-wi

Comment: How does a list of length 5 in col1 `['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', '2']`, match with 2 lists of 4 in col2? I understand 1 to 1 matches, and even in your simplified version the lengths match, but in this case they dont.

Comment: @BenPap the idea is values in col1 lists need to cycle through each of the values in the sublists in col2. The mismatch in list lengths won't matter - just trying to run function against col1 item 1 on col2 sublist 1 item 1,2,x, and col2 sublist 2 item 1,2,3,x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
# Generate DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['col1','col2'])

# Clean Data (strip out trailing commas on some words)
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda lst: [x.rstrip(',') for x in lst])

# 1. List comprehension Technique
# zip provides pairs of col1, col2 rows
result = [[get_top_matches(u, [v]) for u in x for w in y for v in w] for x, y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]

# 2. DataFrame Apply Technique
def func(x, y):
return [get_top_matches(u, [v]) for u in x for w in y for v in w] 

df['func_scores'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row['col1'], row['col2']), axis = 1)

# Verify two methods are equal
print(df['func_scores'].equals(pd.Series(result)))  # True

print(df['func_scores'].to_string(index=False))
```

Thanks all who helped